# meaning of each stuff generated by cmake

Tags: cmake

I am new to cmake.

I write the simplest CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(hello_proj)
add_executable(hello helloworld.cpp)
```

with my simplest helloworld.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Then I type: `cmake .`

So `cmake` runs to produce `makefile`. then `ls` you will see:

```
swpe2@CIA-023251:~/Documents/mystuff/Academics/2015summer/learnCmake$ ls
CMakeCache.txt  CMakeFiles  cmake_install.cmake  CMakeLists.txt  hello  helloworld.cpp  Makefile
```

However, I wish to know what's the function of the following new stuff, why they are there:

`CMakeCache.txt  CMakeFiles  cmake_install.cmake`
.

Comment: I think you should clarify your question right after you'll check https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ and https://cmake.org/overview/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you expect? That we explain you every detail of a complete build-system? Use an out-of-source build and you are fine.

The only things you might need to know:

- `CMakeCache.txt` caches the configure results. If you rerun CMake you might want to delete the file, then CMake will re-configure every value. That's necessary if you installed third-party software or changed the variables you pass to CMake.
- `CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log` When CMake configures and a test fails, you can find have a look into this look to figure out the reasons why a test failed.
- `CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log` Similar to the error log, but for successful checks.

All other files are for internal purposes and should not bother you. Later, for advanced tasks, this might change.